# Slow performance for package with XML destination column

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have done several SSIS packages over the past few months to move data from a legacy database to a SQL Server database. It normally takes 10-20 minutes to process around 5 millions of records depending on the transformation.

The issue I am experiencing with one of my package is a very poor performance because one of the columns in my destination is of the SQL Server XML data type.

```
 Data comes in like this: 5
 A script creates a Unicode string like this: <XmlData><Value>5</Value></XmlData>
 Destination is simply a column with XML data type
```

This is really slow. Any advice?
I did a SQL Trace and notice that in behind the scene SSIS is executing on each row a convert before the insert:

```
 declare @p as xml
 set @p=convert(xml,N'<XmlData><Value>5</Value></XmlData>')
```

Comment: Which versions are you using for source and destination?

Comment: I assume that's the destination. What's the "legacy database"?

Comment: The source is also SQL, 2005. I implemented "mceda" suggestion that is listed below and it reduce my processing time drastically...all good now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a temporary table to store the resulting 5 million records without the XML transformation and then use SQL Server itself to move them from tempDB to the final destination:

```
INSERT INTO final_destination (...)
SELECT cast(N'<XmlData><Value>5</Value></XmlData>' AS XML) AS batch_converted_xml, col1, col2, colX 
FROM   #tempTable
```

If 5.000.000 turns to be too much data for a single batch, you can do it in smaller batches (100k lines should work like a charm).

The record captured by the profiler looks like an OleDB transformation with one command per line.